# Remove/Change Cursor when doing a Drag Drop

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop, cursor

How can I remove the cursor when doing a Drag and Drop. I put this code  this.Cursor = Cursors.None on the start up of the program and DragDrop event, it works well on the the startup but in dragdrop the cursor is visible.. any tips?

Answer (score 1):

You probably should set the cursor in the `DragOver` event.

(Also if the drag drop effect remains: `e.Effects = DragDropEffects.None;`)